# Expandable Table Rows w/ Jquery UI Accordian

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, expandable

I am working on an Ebay style listing where auctions are listed vertically and in an effort to save space, I would like to show minimal information that can be expanded to include more details. The JQuery UI Accordion example is perfect and is very smooth, but I don't think I can divide the "header" up into sub-sections properly.

I have found other examples but they all make use of Tables rather than divs and they sliding animations seem choppy.

The [Accordian](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) script is perfect with just the exception of being unable to divide up the header. As Table examples are not smooth, what would be the best way to do this?

Here is an example image I found on another post...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Accordion. You need to put your markup the way you like it into Accordion's header tag. I would advise to use `<ul>` with some CSS similar to [CSS Nav Bar](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp)

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't clear on that but that makes much more sense now.